# iphone - improve INSERT into sqlite

Tags: ios, sqlite

In my app, I need to INSERT multiple times some entry.
Each time, I am using this function:

```
- (int)  insertFunction:(NSString *)stringa{
    NSDate * start = [NSDate date];

    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    NSString *file = [self getWritableDBPath];

    if (sqlite3_open([file UTF8String] , &_database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",stringa];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            //NSLog(@"Contact added");

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to add contact");
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(_database);
    int row_id = (int)sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(_database);

    NSLog(@"SINGLE INSERT took: %f", -[start timeIntervalSinceNow]);

    return row_id;

}
```

that took about 0.020 second, and make my app frezing about 5 second.

-EDIT-  My getWritableDBPath is:

```
- (NSString *) getWritableDBPath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:DATABASE_NAME];
}
```

What I can do to improve that time? For example, avoiding to open the data base each time? In this case how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. For avoiding UI hang, you can execute the database operation in a different thread. 2. This cast is unnecessary `NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",stringa];` 3. What are you doing in `[self getWritableDBPath];` ?

Comment: Tx. I just edit with the getWritableDBPath function. And If i remove the cast, it does not improve the time.

Comment: I didn't say that if you remove that cast it will be faster. I just want to communicate that it is unnecessary, no need to convert a string to string again. Also check with sqlite3_exec function.

Comment: i have attach below answer, just change query and also dont forget release  stetment object

Comment: Why you don't use `Core Data`?

Comment: if my answer ok plz tick as right or give point

Comment: The code looks ok unless you are calling it hundreds times. If you called it only several times but the app hangs 5 second, try running Product -> Profile -> Time Profiler to identify what the cause is first.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the `closeDatabase` call, if the version of SQLite you are using is new enough it will probably have placed your writes into the WAL and will be committing them into the main database.  Although 5 seconds does seems quite slow.

For your other comment about leaving the database open, simply call the open one time only and hold onto the sqlite3* handle in a class variable, and then close it when the class gets dealloc'ed, you will see much better performance.

Comment: Tx. How coull Try to replace the close statement? and How coud I call only one time the open/ close database?